# Probability of 2 people to meet exactly $k$ people.

Tags: probability

> There are $M$ man and $W$ woman at an event. Everyone has $\hat p$ probability to meet each other (of the same gender, and they can't meet people from the opposite gender). After the event, we pick out a random man and a random woman and ask them how many people they met. What's the probability of getting $k$ when we sum the $2$ numbers?

I think I should do it this way:

Let $p(x, y)$ be the probability of a person meets $y$ people out of $x$, then we are looking for the probability
$$P(k)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{k}p(M, n)p(W, k-n)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{k}p(W, n)p(M, k-n)$$

The problem is that I can't get the $p(x, y)$ function. I know that $p(2, 1)=\hat p$, and I think $p(x, 1)=(x-1)\hat p$, because the person would have $\hat p$ chance to meet every other people, but I have no idea for the $y>1$ case.

Comment: This sounds like it should follow a [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution).  Also, you should note that a person cannot "meet themselves", so our randomly selected man will have met between $0$ and $M-1$ other men.  Our randomly selected man should have met exactly $n$ people with probability $\binom{M-1}{n}p^n(1-p)^{M-1-n}$

Comment: What does it mean that “Everyone has $\hat p$ probability to meet each other”?

Comment: @JMoravitz Isn't binomial distribution for sampling with replacement?

Comment: @MichaelHoppe my interpretation is that for each potential meeting between two people of the same gender, it actually occurred with probability $p$ and it did not occur with probability $1-p$, and further each such potential meeting's occurrence is independent of any other potential meeting's occurrence.

Comment: @Botond if you want to think of it that way, sure... and what is being sampled and being potentially replaced is "The meeting occurred" vs "The meeting didn't occur."  I prefer to think of it as that binomial distribution is used when we have some number of independent "yes/no" questions, each question having the same probability of having been a "yes."

Comment: @MichaelHoppe I think JMoravitz could draw up the problem better. Sorry for the not clear question.

Comment: That being said, you did not explicitly state that the meetings' occurrences should occur *independently* of one another.  Assuming they were in fact independent occurrences, then this is exactly the situation to use binomial distributions in.  If they weren't independent, then the problem is missing a great deal of information.  For extreme example, flip an unfair coin with probability $p$ of landing heads.  If it lands heads, then everyone meets everyone else of their gender.  If it comes up tails, noone meets anyone else.  This satisfies that some specific two people met with probability p.

Comment: As a final comment, assuming my interpretation is in fact the correct one you should find that since the situation is so symmetrical there will be a very nice simplification that can be made using [vandermonde's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde's_identity).

Comment: @JMoravitz Yes, the meetings are independent of each other. Could you explaint a bit more the "if you want to think of it that way, sure..." part?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77777/discussion-between-jmoravitz-and-botond).

Comment: Then the sum of the people they met follows a $Bin(N+M-2, \hat{p})$ distribution.